# Generate random points on 10-dimensional unit sphere

Tags: python, random

I need to generate a vector sampled uniformly with 10 directions (a collection of 10 random numbers) which lies over a unit sphere. So, the sum of the squares of the 10 values should be 1.

This is the exact question for which I need to generate those points:

> Implement the Perceptron algorithm and run it on the following
>   synthetic data sets in ℝ<sup>10</sup>: pick ∗ = [1,0,0,…,0]; generate 1000
>   points  by sampling uniformly at random over the unit sphere and
>   then removing those that have margin  smaller than 0.1; generate
>   label  = sign((∗)<sup>T</sup>).

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Andrex suggested, here is the right solution:

```
import numpy as np
import math

s = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)

norm=math.sqrt(sum(s*s))
result=s/norm
```

where `result` is the answer. You can evaluate the result:

```
sum([x*x for x in result])
1.0
```

Comment: I think that is not correct! You have to sample from normal distribution and normalize

Comment: I do not see why it should come from a normal distribution? in what part of the question we are restricted to a normal distribution? after all, when you apply an sqrt, it is not normal anymore, so what is the point?

Comment: If we want a **Uniform** distribution on the sphere, we have to be rigorous. There is a strong mathematical foundation behind my statement

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444700/uniform-distribution-on-the-surface-of-unit-sphere you can see here!

Comment: You're actually right!  Thanks for sharing the link, very good to know!

Comment: Thank you @Andrex I ended up using the same approach.

Comment: well, norm could be computed directly in NumPy: "norm=np.linalg.norm(s)".

Answer (score 5):

There is a [math theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444700/uniform-distribution-on-the-surface-of-unit-sphere) saying that if `X = (X1,...,XN)` is a vector with `Xi` the standard normal distribution, then `X/NORM(X)` is uniform in the unit sphere, where `NORM` is the euclidean norm. So you have to sample 10 points from a standard normal distribution (using numpy?) and then normalize the result.

Comment: `X/NORM(X)` if you take the  norm, the result is 1

Comment: What is the definition of a point on the unit sphere!? is that `NORM(X) = 1`